# Low resolution Image to High resolution

Tags: algorithms, image-processing, image-manipulation

Is it possible to scale a low resolution image to a highier resolution upto the point with minimum effect on quality, sharpness and other notable attributes of an image.

Comment: There are many existing algorithms available. Most algorithms have theoretical foundations, but it is the human user who must decide which one is most suitable for each image's particular purpose. I'd like to remind that there's no one-size-fits-all algorithm. Lanczos comes close, but there're plenty of people who would chose another one for some niche purposes. You can search for lists of image resize algorithms in many places, including the image processing libraries you're using right now, or APIs which are bundled as part of the OS.

Comment: [Let's enhance that.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhF_56SxrGk)

Comment: see [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Answer (score 4):

Sure, but why? If you have one red pixel, you can make that four red pixels at a slightly higher resolution or a billion red pixels at a lot higher resolution.

The image itself is the same, you're just spending four or a billion times the data to encode it.

What you might be asking is if you can take a one pixel picture of me, then make a four pixel image or a billion pixel image, each looking more accurately like me. And you can't do *that*. Or I mean, you could, but the picture would be wrong. It requires algorithms making educated guesses about what to fill in those missing pixels with. Some algorithms are decent at that, but unless they have a high resolution image of me already, it's all guesswork.